# How to set variable dependent bounds on parameters with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. The function contains two fitting parameters `loc` and `scale`. The function includes the term `(x - loc)**3/2`, where `x` is the independent variable. The function is undefined where `loc > x`, so I need some bounds on the fitting parameter space. The `scipy` documentation has an example for the simple case in which the bounds are fixed but doesn't have an example for the case I'm describing. Is it possible to do what I want or have I just misunderstood something? The full fitting function is as follows

```py
def levy(x, scale, loc):
 return np.sqrt(scale / 2*np.pi) * np.exp(-scale/(2*x - 2*loc) ) / (x - loc)**(3/2)
```

Comment: Should the bound for loc be "loc < min(x)", that is, loc must be greater than min(x)?

Comment: If min(x) = 0 and the optimizer tries a value of loc = 1, then we have x - loc = -1 and the function value is undefined.

Comment: Then loc must be less than min(x), that is, the upper bound for loc is min(x) and the lower bound is -numpy.inf. The upper and lower bounds for scale can be set to numpy.inf and -numpy.inf, that is, no bounds on scale.